# Pax11publish on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio

On ubuntu 18.04, I could simply switch from local pulseaudio to server {ip} with commandline:
pax11publish -e -S {ip}
On ubuntu 20.04, this has no effect, audio remains local.
No error message or other cues.
Is this a bug, or has this feature been 'improved beyond repair'?

Comment: Addition: running a single command with PULSE_SERVER set in the environment still works, e.g. $ PULSE_SERVER=192.168.1.5 audacious. To apply this setting to _every_ application requires (un)setting PULSE_SERVER in .profile _before_ starting X, which is troublesome.

Comment: Addition2: New in 20.04 is that the gdm processes are no longer started. Could this be the cause? If so, how to restore?

Comment: Addition 3: tried kubuntu 20.04. Same problem here. The problem appears to be related to PA itself, not the DM.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the removal of gconf support (which - as it appears - has been marked as deprecated for some time).
Good new is, there is a much better solution:
On a running system, simply enter (parameters shown work for me):
$ pacmd load-module module-tunnel-sink-new server=192.168.1.5 
sink_name=Remote channels=2 rate=48000
The remote device appears beside the local sink (output) devices, so these stay available for selection.
Problem solved.